# capturing document click event using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a case where on clicking a link, I am showing a tooptip. I want to hide the tool tip when the user clicks anywhere else on the screen(even some other link).
Below is the code I have...

```
$('a.tooltip').click(function(event){
    $('a.tooltip span').hide();
    $(this).children("span").show();
});
```

The above function shows/hide the tooltips when clicked on the a tags.

```
$(document).click(function(event){
    if(event.target != 'a.pull-right plus tooltip'){
        $('a.tooltip span').hide();
    }
});
```

Since event.target gives me the entire HTML target, I am not able to distinguish between clicks. Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT : Try this way maybe :

```
$(document).not('a.tooltip').click(function(event){
    $('a.tooltip span').hide();
});

$('a.tooltip').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('a.tooltip span').hide();
    $(this).children("span").show();
});
```

Comment: You might want to change the selector to `'html :not(a.tooltip)'`, since the html tag can also have markup that affects the body.

Comment: @Oliboy50 It is preventing the tooltip to come up at all. I put a console.log to check. Even clicking on the link, the function is getting executed